# Early science fiction novel with people traversing a rectangular planet/satellite with lava fields and lava creatures?

Tags: story-identification, books

I think this was a story bundled in a single book with "War of the Wing Men" and that it had the same three characters as "War of the Wing Men" but my memory may be misleading me.

I only remember people arrive on a rectangular planet/moon and have to traverse it. There is lava and lava monsters, maybe centaur like with hard lava resistant hooves. When they change faces the gravity also changes greatly and lava is replaced by a different terrain.

That is about all I remember except for greatly enjoying the book. I think it is early maybe 50s but could easily be decades later. I want to get a copy for my son.

Comment: "War of the Wing Men" is part of a series of 5 or 6 books by Poul Anderson, called the "[Polesotechnic League](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53155-future-history-of-the-polesotechnic-league)" series. I won't try to give a definitive answer, since I haven't read any of them, but from reading synopses, the one that seems to match the best is _[Mirkheim]_.

Comment: What does "when they change faces" mean?

Comment: "War of the Wing Men" appeared in an Ace Double with "The Snows of Ganymede".  The latter work is available online here https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v32n03_1955-Winter/page/n39 but a quick browse makes me think it isn't the answer.

Comment: I don't recall any rectangular planets in the Polesotechnic League series, which I've read several times, but not for many years. Are you sure it was the same characters as _War of the Wing-Men_?

Comment: Thank you all very much for responding unfortunately it is not Mirkeim that has a too involved storyline. the story I read is limited to travelling across the planetoid?/moon/large lump of rock. Its rectangular nature is the key ingredient of the story It may have been in a short story collection, the other thing I thought I remembered was that maybe it was written by Frederick pohl but it think that is another red herring as I couldn't find anything that matched in his novels.

Comment: Changing the faces means going around the rectangular satellites edge onto another surface, on a dice from the 6 side to the 1 side for example I see that is unclear but didn't know how to edit my original post.

Comment: No not at all sure it was the characters from It may not even have anything to do with those characters perhaps I just read the lava tracking story just before war of the wing men because it is linked in my memory but I am not sure why polytechnic league is probably a red Herring. And yes the Ganymede  story is in the spot where I thought this short story was I jumped for joy when I saw the war of the wingmen came as a double but was deflated again when I saw what was in there Ganymede has a much more involved plot.

Comment: I am sure however that the story I am after has a simple trecking storyline but the rectangular nature of the planet/satellite is the clincher I read a lot of old SF and never seem that anywhere else.

Comment: See if [any of these other titles](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57474+c) from the February 1958 issue of _Astounding_, where the novel was first serialized, rings a bell. Part 2 appeared as"The Man who Counts" in March ([link](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57579+c)) and part 3 in April ([link](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57396+c)).

Comment: @chuck thanks for the reply. So the planetoid is like a cube or die and all the surfaces are different.  That may help out.

Comment: I've looked at most of the astounding articles, no joy yet some are a bit hard to track but persisting, thanks for the link. I should say I've never read any astounding magazines, only novels or novels including 10 or so short stories.

Comment: yes but more accurately like a brick but maybe more elongated. This then gave the different gravities on the different faces because of the different distance from the centre. Yes one surface was all lava with the creatures. I cannot remember what the other faces held unfortunately.

Comment: Poul Anderson always took great care with the astronomy of his worlds. I doubt he would make a rectangular world unless it was clearly an artifact.